# By the end of Babylon 5, which races achieved "First One"-like status?

Tags: babylon-5

We know at the end of Babylon 5 humanity has achieved First One like status, but what about the other races? I think I heard somewhere that the Minbari also achieved First One like status while all the other races are still around but just stagnated.

Comment: How do you define "First Ones-like status"? The Babylon 5 wiki seems to define the "First Ones" as those that were around before the younger races, Humans and the Minbari would therefore never reach that status.

Comment: @Edlothiad I assumed he meant became energy beings like Vorlons, which was implied that humans achieved at the end of the series.

Comment: I said First One "like" status because by a million AD humanity has reached to the point that they are beings of pure energy that can shift back to their human form. They also have encounter suits much like the Vorlons which implies that humanity has stuck around to guide the younger races of that generation.

Comment: Oh, is that what “the dawn of the third age” was about? (I never saw the last season.)

Answer (score 12):

Humans became like the First Ones as shown in "The Deconstruction of Falling Stars". As JMS answers, quoted in the JMS Speaks section of the [Lurker's Guide page for "The Deconstruction of Falling Stars"](http://midwinter.com/lurk/countries/us/guide/088.html):

> [Q:] What about the other races?
>
> [JMS:] The Minbari eventually make it; the Narn and Centauri do not. They don't die out, they just don't hit a state of First One-ishness, which is darn close to immortality (barring violence).

No other comments on any of the other races we've seen.